# Using intern in java Strings

Tags: java, string, variables, object

I am trying to understand Java's `String` class but I am having a hard time understanding the situation described below.

Consider the following example snippet:

```
String x = new String("Hey");
String y = "Hey";
```

If I use `bool = y == x.intern();` the variable `bool` will equal **`true`**.

My question is:

When I make a declaration like this:

```
String b = "h";
String a = b.intern + "ey";
boolean x = a == "hey";
```

`x`'s value would be **`false`** but when I make `a = (b + "ey").intern();` `x`'s value will be **`true`**.

**Why won't `x = true` in the second example?** Is it because the declarations in the first example not alike? If yes what are the differences?

Comment: The following link may be helpful to you: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/06/26/all-about-intern

Comment: `String + String` evaluates to a new String which is *not* magically interned: it does not try to find existing interned Strings with the same content. Now, if both String expressions are literals then the entire expression might be *folded* during compilation - which means only the *result* is found in the compiled output and is subject to standard intern rules - but that leads to a different cute case: `("h" + "ey") == "hey"` is true. As soon as folding is *eliminated* (i.e. with a variable) this goes away.

Comment: @TariqAyman I did some edits to your question, trying to improve its formatting. Please review it if you feel any point of your question was lost.

Comment: You might want to check this related answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/422353

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your first example:

```
String y = "Hey";
```

Java automatically interns string literals such as this ([JLS section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class
>   String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings
>   that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned"
>   so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

So when you call `x.intern()`, you get the interned copy of `"Hey"`, so they are the same object and `==` returns `true`.

But in the second example, `b.intern()` is a method call that is evaluated at runtime, and Java's concatenation operator will return a new `String` (not interned), which is a different object than the string literal `"hey"` (interned already), so `==` returns `false` (different objects).

**EDIT**

To clear up what happens with the string concatenation, turn to [JLS Section 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object
>   that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters
>   of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand
>   operand in the newly created string.
>
> The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a
>   compile-time constant expression (§15.28).

But, `b.intern() + "ey";` is *not* a compile-time constant expression, so the resultant `String` object has not been interned, and `==` will detect that it's a different object than the interned `"hey"`.

Comment: Thank for clearing it out but if you make a new String like b = "h" + "ey" this is a concatenated String but it will equal "hey" is it because there are no objects ?

Comment: The compiler optimizes out the `+` and automatically interns the result.

Comment: @LeeMeador That's true for a compile-time constant expression such as `"h" + "ey"`, but not for something involving a method call, such as `b.intern() + "ey"`.

Comment: Yes. Maybe I didn't make it clear my last comment referred to OP's questions about "h" + "ey".

Answer (score 3):

This one creates a string and stores it:

```
String a = b.intern() + "ey";
```

This one creates a string, interns it and stores the interned version:

```
String a = (b + "ey").intern();
```

All interned strings with the same content are `==`

All string literals (strings supplied in the form "hey") are interned by the compiler internally.

Strings that are not interned but have the same content are only `equal()` and not `==`

For posterity, one more ... where the compiler optimizes out the `+` resulting in "hey" and interns it just as it would the string literal "hey"

```
String a = "h" + "ey";
```

Comment: thank you but then why would String b = "h" + "ey" equals "hey" is it not the same as b.intern() + "ey" ?

Comment: Neither is interned so they are not `==`. They will be `equal()`. Same content. Different location in memory.

Comment: @Lee Meador - `intern()` is a *method*

Comment: @LeeMeador but if you do this String b = "h" + "ey" and bool  = b == "hey" bool value would be true

Comment: @Tariq the compiler turns "h" + "ey" into "hey" before the code ever runs.

Answer (score 0):

Java concatenates `String`s by using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

`b.intern() + "ey"` turns into something similar to 
 `new StringBuilder(b.intern()).append("ey").toString()`. This creates a new `String`, so it will not be `==` to `"hey"`.